# FAB improperly placed temporarily?

Tags: android, layout, floating-action-button

I have a FAB anchored to a LinearLayout. It is correctly positioned in the Android Studio preview. When the fragment is first loaded, the FAB is not located in the correct position (the one in the preview from AS). Certain actions after the initial creation of the Fragment then cause the FAB to move to the correct location (focusing an EditText, going to a new Activity and returning, etc.).

Incorrect placement:
[image: Incorrect placement]

Correct placement:
[image]

Here is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/distance"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:id="@+id/meas_unit"
                        tools:text="ft"/>
                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/distance_seekbar"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:max="95"
                        android:progress="25"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                tools:context=".ui.main.MainFragment">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/putters"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:elevation="6dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="127dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button4" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/top"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I don't recall having this issue in older versions of Android supprt design library, it seems to have surfaced when I updated `com.android.support:design:23.1.1` to `com.android.support:design:24.2.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out the root cause of why this doesn't work (I still suspect a bug in in the Support Design library), but I resolved this issue by switching the anchored view to `@id/bottom` and correspondingly changing the gravity to `top|right|end`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are anchoring to "top" not "input_layout"

`<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/input_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"/>`

Comment: Anchoring to input_layout causes the FAB to be position in the bottom right of the screen, which is not what I want. The correct positioning is shown in the second screenshot.

Comment: Note on formatting: you should add four spaces at the beginning of each line of code rather than using back ticks.